# Is an Ubuntu Restore possible?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, backup, 14.10, restore

I would like to take a complete snapshot of my current Ubuntu 14.10 system, much like a Nandroid backup on Android phones.

Is there a utility which allows one to **backup** the current system as it is, and then restore it later, being ready from the word go, **without having to reinstall** any of the software?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make and restore incremental snapshots of hard disk](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78997/how-to-make-and-restore-incremental-snapshots-of-hard-disk)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should help you out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQKQiP7JU-8

Answer (score 0):

there is a very nice software for this called [TimeShift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html)

You can backup your current installation any time to some other partition whenever you want and can restore if something goes wrong.

*TimeShift for Linux is a application that provides functionality similar to the System Restore feature in Windows and the Time Machine tool in Mac OS. TimeShift protects your system by taking incremental snapshots of the file system at regular intervals. These snapshots can be restored later to bring your system to the exact state it was in at the time when the snapshot was taken.*

It is very simple to use and has good GUI, you dont need to use terminal for this.

Installation:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timeshift
```